# Accordion within Accordion not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to this forum. I hope I am not breaking any rules. I am trying to include accordion within accordion and after a lot of research found this solution on your website. I thought I would start with this and modify what I need to make it work for my specific situation, but this solution does not seem to work for me and looks like it worked for the person asking. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>



<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>
content
 </p>
</div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like its working fine here.  What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: I just rolled back - the problem is that the script is **before** the accordeon

Comment: I think the problem is that in the first example the JS was in the head-Tag. This won't work if the dom ist not loaded. He has to push the script to the ende of body or copy the script into document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ ...your script hier...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the `<script>` **after** the accordeon

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style>
  button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
  }

  div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
  }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Or else wrap your script in:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Otherwise, when it gets to the part:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
```

it cannot get the element by class name that does not yet exist, and `acc` will be an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using `jQuery` https://jsfiddle.net/apjnf4xf/1/

```js
$('.accordion').click(function(){
  $('.panel').slideUp();
  $(this).next('div.panel').slideDown();
});
```

```css
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the script before the browser even knows that your document has elements with class `accordion`. Run the script after the window has loaded or as the other answers here suggest, include the script after the accordion HTML markup.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; 
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load',setUpAccordion);
function setUpAccordion(){
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>



<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<p>
content
 </p>
</div>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. You just made my day. Thank you so much everybody!